# How can I convert a Set of objects into a Map of the Object's fields to a set of fields using Java streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

If I have some class A

```
public class A {
   String name;

   String value;
}
```

I have a Set which I want to convert into a `Map<String, Set<String>>`, which maps A.name to a set of A.value, using the stream class, since many instances of A will share the same name String, but none will share the same value String. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a `Map<String, Set<String>>`, which maps `A.name` to a set of `A.value`, you need to use the following methods:

- [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--)
- [`collect(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-)
- [`groupingBy(Function<? super T,? extends K> classifier, Collector<? super T,A,D> downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)
- [`mapping(Function<? super T,? extends U> mapper, Collector<? super U,A,R> downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)
- [`toSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--)

```java
Map<String, Set<String>> map = set.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getName,
                                       Collectors.mapping(A::getValue,
                                                          Collectors.toSet())));
```

The code uses method references to getter methods on your `A` class, though lambda expressions can be used instead, e.g. `A::getName` could be replaced with `o -> o.name`.

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate an empty Map before converting, then the conversion will collect using an anonymous function that checks the map to see if it should put a new set or update an existing one.